# IF functions and time format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some excel columns in this format:  01/08/2016  18:40:00

Does anyone know how I can use an IF function to see if the time is greater than 18.00h for example?

Hugely appreciative of any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula, it will return TRUE/FALSE:

```
=MOD(A1,1)>TIME(18,0,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`HOUR()` will return the hour so:

```
=IF(HOUR(A1) > 18, "is greater", "is less or equal")
```

Comment: To *'see if the time is greater than 18.00h'* shouldn't that be `HOUR(A1) >= 18` ? 06:15pm is **after** 18.00h.